# Subquery cannot appear in an Insert Values statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have the following query in SQL Server CE which gives me an error during the execution time:

```
INSERT INTO trans_rel(trans, sale_purch_id, inc_exp_id)
 VALUES('p', 104, (select MAX(expence_id) from c_expence))
```

The error is this:

> Subquery cannot appear in an Insert Values statement.

What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
INSERT INTO trans_rel
SELECT 'p', '102', MAX(expence_id)
FROM c_expence
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what your are looking for:

```
INSERT INTO trans_rel(trans, sale_purch_id, inc_exp_id)
SELECT 'p' as 'trans', '104' as 'sale_purch_id', MAX(expence_id) AS inc_exp_id
FROM c_expence;
```